# Python Wrapper for TA-Lib: Import Failure [change path did not work]

Tags: python

i did installed ta-lib and export path did not help..

```
~$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import talib
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py:1031: UserWarning: /home/xun/.python-eggs is            
writable by group/others and vulnerable to attack when used with get_resource_filename. Consider a     
more secure location (set with .set_extraction_path or the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable).
warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/talib/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/talib/common.py", line 7, in <module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/talib/common.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: libta_lib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Help me plz..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed `libta_lib.so.0` already, I think you made a typo in the export path.

Change `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` then.

Comment: Thx . it works now..but with some warnings. `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py:1031: UserWarning: /home/xun/.python-eggs is writable by group/others and vulnerable to attack when used with get_resource_filename. Consider a more secure location (set with .set_extraction_path or the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment variable).
  warnings.warn(msg, UserWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel.py:626: UserWarning: Installed openpyxl is not supported at this time. Use >=1.6.1 and <2.0.0.
  .format(openpyxl_compat.start_ver, openpyxl_compat.stop_ver))
`